# How to read a binary file byte by byte?

Tags: delphi

I used this code to ready one letter each time but for text file.

```
var
myFile : TextFile;
letter : char;
begin
  AssignFile(myFile, 'Test.txt');
  // Reopen the file for reading
  Reset(myFile);

  while not Eof(myFile) do begin
    // Proces one line at a time
    while not Eoln(myFile) do begin
      Read(myFile, letter);   // Read and display one letter at a time
    end;
    ReadLn(myFile, text);
  end;

  // Close the file for the last time
  CloseFile(myFile);
```

What I can use to do the same for binary files also byte by byte ?

Comment: How do you want to interpret the binary? And why do you want to read one character at a time? That's slow. And why are you using old school Pascal IO. That's no longer idiomatic.

Comment: You answered only one of three questions.

Comment: Use a stream to do this. A file stream. If performance matters you'll want to buffer it.

Comment: Also, if you want to treat the file as a "binary file" the concept of "end-of-line" is nonsense. So `Readln()` and `Eoln()` are nonsense functions in that context. All they do is mess around with your ability to process the special bytes that are used to denote EOL in a _normal text file_. I suggest you [edit] your question and explain what you ***really want to do***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention which version of Delphi you are using. If you are using a relatively new one, you can do as follows. If you get an error on the TBufferedFileStream, remove that line and uncomment the one with TFileStream.

```
PROGRAM ByteReader;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

USES SysUtils, Classes;

VAR
  S : TStream;
  O : Int64;
  B : BYTE;

BEGIN
  TRY
    // Open the file as a buffered file stream in Read/Only mode
    S:=TBufferedFileStream.Create(ParamStr(1),fmOpenRead);
    // If you get an error that TBufferedFileStream is unknown, use TFileStream instead.
    // It's compatible, but much slower
    // S:=TFileStream.Create(ParamStr(1),fmOpenRead);
    TRY
      // Reapeat for each byte (numbered 1 through the size (length) of the stream
      FOR O:=1 TO S.Size DO BEGIN
        // Read a single byte from the stream
        S.Read(B,SizeOf(BYTE));
        // Do whatever you want to do with it - here I am dumping it as a hex value
        WRITE(IntToHex(B))
      END
    FINALLY
      // Release the stream (and close the file)
      S.Free
    END
  EXCEPT
    ON E:Exception DO WRITELN(E.ClassName,': ',E.Message)
  END
END.
```

Comment: If you are going to use Read you must check the return value for errors. Or, use Read Buffer.

Comment: Thanks. I am using Tokyo edition but I am getting "I/O error 105" what this mean ?

Comment: I would use SizeOf(B) rather than SizeOf(BYTE) here. Just one more insurance that the size of the buffer and the parameter that specifies it are always in sync.